# Method call returning invalid data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this javascript (react) code using the `.find()` method to search through an array of objects to find one with a matching id to one gotten from `useParams()` method but when I console log to check it, It returns array with a corresponding id but with the data from the data from the first object in the array. could someone please point out what mistake I'm making?

***Here's the array of objects***

```
    const Merchandise = [
{
    id: 5,
    productImage: "images/heroImage.png",
    productName: "Africhella Lip Gloss",
    productPrice: "3000",
    productDescription: "Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam quidem deserunt id repellendus ratione reprehenderit animi qui quae repellat voluptatem, quisquam amet quo vel ullam odit minima architecto error tempore"
},
{
    id: 6,
    productImage: "images/lipBalm.png",
    productName: "Africhella Lip Butter",
    productPrice: "3000",
    productDescription: "Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam quidem deserunt id repellendus ratione reprehenderit animi qui quae repellat voluptatem, quisquam amet quo vel ullam odit minima architecto error tempore"
},
{
    id: 7,
    productImage: "images/lipScrub.png",
    productName: "Africhella Lip Scrub",
    productPrice: "3000",
    productDescription: "Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam 
    quidem deserunt id repellendus ratione reprehenderit animi qui quae repellat voluptatem, 
    quisquam amet quo vel ullam odit minima architecto error tempore"
},
{
    id: 8,
    productImage: "images/lipCareBundle.jpg",
    productName: "Africhella Lip Care Bundle",
    productPrice: "3000",
    productDescription: "Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam 
    quidem deserunt id repellendus ratione reprehenderit animi qui quae repellat voluptatem, 
    quisquam amet quo vel ullam odit minima architecto error tempore"
},
{
    id: 9,
    productImage: "images/lashes.png",
    productName: "Africhella Lashes",
    productPrice: "3000",
    productDescription: "Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam 
        quidem deserunt id repellendus ratione reprehenderit animi qui quae repellat 
        voluptatem, quisquam amet quo vel ullam odit minima architecto error tempore"
}]

export default Merchandise
```

***The React Code***

```
let id = useParams()
let productId = id.id
console.log(productId)

let product = Merchandise.find(M => M.id = productId)
console.log(product)
```

**This Is What The Output Currently Looks Like**

```
5
{id: '5', productImage: 'images/heroImage.png', productName: 'Africhella Lip Gloss', productPrice: '3000', productDescription: 'Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicin…uo vel ullam odit minima architecto error tempore'}
6
{id: '6', productImage: 'images/heroImage.png', productName: 'Africhella Lip Gloss', productPrice: '3000', productDescription: 'Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicin…uo vel ullam odit minima architecto error tempore'}
7
{id: '7', productImage: 'images/heroImage.png', productName: 'Africhella Lip Gloss', productPrice: '3000', productDescription: 'Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicin…uo vel ullam odit minima architecto error tempore'}
8
{id: '8', productImage: 'images/heroImage.png', productName: 'Africhella Lip Gloss', productPrice: '3000', productDescription: 'Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicin…uo vel ullam odit minima architecto error tempore'}
9
{id: '9', productImage: 'images/heroImage.png', productName: 'Africhella Lip Gloss', productPrice: '3000', productDescription: 'Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicin…uo vel ullam odit minima architecto error tempore'}
```

Comment: You need to use the equality check operator (`==` or `===`) not assignment operator (`=`) in `find`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
let product = Merchandise.find(M => M.id === productId)
```

Just update this line

Comment: I tried that but it returns undefined as the output